# Why does IBM's arduino-lmic example for abp activation have only 2 keys?

Tags: lorawan

As far as I know the LoraWan v1.1 Spec uses the following keys:

- **FNwkSIntKey**: In order secure the message integrity on the data that a node sends to the server.
- **SNwkSIntKey**: In order to secure the message integrity on the data that a node receives from the
  network.
- **NwkSEncKey**: In order to encrypt the payload data transfered over the network.

Also I have seen that also supports the following keys when performs a join procedure:

- **JSIntKey**: That is used for message integrity during join procedures.
- **JSEncKey**: That is used for message encryption during join procedures.

Also I have looked over a current abp activation [code example](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic/blob/master/examples/ttn-abp/ttn-abp.ino) using IBM's lmic library.

And I saw only the having a network session key and an Application session key according to the snippet:

```
static const PROGMEM u1_t NWKSKEY[16] = { 0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6, 0xAB, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xCF, 0x4F, 0x3C };

static const u1_t PROGMEM APPSKEY[16] = { 0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6, 0xAB, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xCF, 0x4F, 0x3C };
```

And I wonder why they have only 2 session keys. So I want to ask:

- Do they support the version 1.0.x and not the latest 1.1 version?
- If they support the version 1.1 do they use only 2 keys for backwards compartibility (the documentation states that **FNwkSIntKey**, **SNwkSIntKey**, **NwkSEncKey** should have the same value in case of Backwards compartibility)?
- If yes how I will use it in order to support the full non-backwards compartible spec 1.1 of LoraWan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do they support the version 1.0.x and not the latest 1.1 version?

Indeed.

Though I'm not sure of the status of the original LMiC library, the Arduino port you're referring to is based on LMiC 1.5 and indeed only supports LoRaWAN 1.0.x. It's not explicitly noted in [its README](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic), but looking at [the changes](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic/commits/master) you'll see that the last meaningful commit dates back to August 2017, while LoRaWAN 1.1.x was not released until November that year.

Beware that your LoRaWAN provider might not be supporting 1.1 either. (Like the public network of The Things Network only supports 1.0.x right now.)